# Mongo DB aggregation pipeline doesn't work with elemMatch operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have tried using mongo db aggregation pipeline with the elemMatch operator but it doesn't output the result that i need, but if i use the same conditions inside a find() it works perfectly. plz help me with this issue

working version when using find()

```
Bookings.find(
      {
        sessionDates: { $elemMatch: { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate } },
        tourId: tourId,
        sessionStatus: "PENDING"
      }
    )
```

not working when using with aggregation

```
    Bookings.aggregate(
          [
            {
              $match: {
                sessionDates: { $elemMatch: { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate } },
                tourId: tourId,
                sessionStatus: "PENDING"
              }
            }
          ]
        );
```

here is a sample of the data I am using

```
{
    "sessionDates": [
        "2022-05-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        "2022-05-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "2022-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "_id": "6228592690b8903618a95280",
    "tourId": "62270fb22e7c5942d010b151",
    "sessionStatus": "PENDING",
    "createdAt": "2022-03-09T07:37:10.237Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-09T07:38:24.003Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: `sessionDates` is array type? Would be great if you can post the sample collection data. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun I've added a data sample thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Mongoose does not cast aggregation pipeline stages (1)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#versus-aggregation), ([2](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate)) and you have to do it manually and make sure the values have the correct type, in your example you must cast `tourId` to an `ObjectId` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and the same thing for `startDate` and `endDate` if `sessionDates` values type is `Date` and not `String`:

```
Bookings.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        sessionDates: { $elemMatch: { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate } },
        // If sessionDates values type is `Date`
        // sessionDates: { $elemMatch: { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lt: new Date(endDate) } },
        tourId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(tourId),
        sessionStatus: "PENDING"
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks dude I was able to solve this using new Date(startDate) and new Date(endDate) like this for casting manully.