# Data between two date in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch data between two dates the query working fine on mongodb compass using isoDate but same query not working with nodejs

This is my query i am writing in nodejs

```
{
  $match: {
    nPrefered: 0,
    iUserId: ObjectId(iUserId),
    dCreatedAt: {
      $gte: firstDay,
      $lt: lastDay
    }
  }
}
```

And in mongodb compass i am using isodate with same query

```
{
  dCreatedAt: {
    $gte: ISODate('2022-11-01'),
    $lt: ISODate('2022-11-30')
  }
}
```

If i use iso date with nodejs then it's giving isodate is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo DB aggregation pipeline doesn't work with elemMatch operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523441/mongo-db-aggregation-pipeline-doesnt-work-with-elemmatch-operator)

Comment: `ISODate()` is an alias for `new Date()` in the mongo shell.